# How to do a group by and count individual group in sql subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following table:

```
date_trans | customerId
2015-02-01 | 12
2015-02-01 | 14
2015-02-01 | 13
2015-02-01 | 12
2015-02-02 | 13
2015-02-02 | 12
2015-02-02 | 13
2015-02-02 | 14
2015-02-02 | 14
```

I am able to get the total transactions per day with a GROUP BY:

```
SELECT date_trans, COUNT(*) as "Transactions" FROM theTable GROUP BY date_trans

date_trans | Transactions
2015-02-01 | 4
2015-02-02 | 5
```

But I am not able to get the partial numbers from the same date by customers:

```
date_trans | Transactions | "By 12" | "By 13" | "By 14"
2015-02-01 | 4            | 2       | 1       | 1
2015-02-02 | 5            | 1       | 2       | 2
```

I tried to do a group by in the select but it does not work.

How can i achieve this in SQL 2014?

Thank you

Comment: Without "dynamic sql" *(code that writes sql)* you can't get a different number of columns just because your data changed.  You *can* do what you've described, provided that you ***always*** and ***only*** ever want to pivot the data for ***those three specific customers***?  Or, what about a result set that was one row per customer per day?  *(With the columns named `date_trans, customerId, transaction_count`?)*

Comment: The case is actually static customers, Would be nice to be able to dynamically do this. The result set with with one row per customer per day would be achieved by adding customer_id to the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with trans as (
SELECT date_trans, COUNT(*) as "Transactions" 
FROM theTable
GROUP BY date_trans)
, cust as (
SELECT customerid, date_trans, COUNT(*) as "cust_txns" 
FROM theTable
GROUP BY customerid, date_trans)
select c.date_trans,
       t.transactions,
       case when c.customerid = 12 then cust_txns end as "By 12",
       case when c.customerid = 13 then cust_txns end as "By 13",
       case when c.customerid = 14 then cust_txns end as "By 14"   
from trans t join cust c
on t.date_trans = c.date_trans
```

This is one way to do it. However, if you have many customers, you will have to use dynamic SQL.

Edit: To eliminate null values on rows, one more level of grouping is needed as below.

```
with trans as (
SELECT date_trans, COUNT(*) as "Transactions" 
FROM thetable
GROUP BY date_trans)
, cust as (
SELECT customerid, date_trans, COUNT(*) as "cust_txns" 
FROM thetable
GROUP BY customerid, date_trans)
select c.date_trans,
       max(t.transactions) as transactions,
       max(case when c.customerid = 12 then cust_txns end) as "By 12",
       max(case when c.customerid = 13 then cust_txns end) as "By 13",
       max(case when c.customerid = 14 then cust_txns end) as "By 14"   
from trans t join cust c
on t.date_trans = c.date_trans
group by c.date_trans
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5cfd7/6)

Comment: Great answer but, it gives me 3 rows per day, the data is not combined into one row per day. The proper result are there but the other columns are NULL